# RegEx - Return pattern to the right of a text string for URL

Tags: regex, looker-studio, regexp-replace, re2

I'm looking to return the URL string to the right of a specific set of text using RegEx:

URL:

```
www.websitename/countrycode/websitename/contact/thank-you/whitepaper/countrycode/whitepapername.pdf
```

What I would like to just return:

```
/whitepapername.pdf
```

I've tried using `^\w+"countrycode"(\w.*)` but the match won't recognize `countrycode`.

In Google Data Studio, I want to create a new field to remove the beginning of the URL using the `REGEX_REPLACE` function.

Ideally using:

```
REGEX_REPLACE(Page,......)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) function below does the trick, capturing all `(.*)` the characters after the last `countrycode`, where `Page` represents the respective field:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page, ".*(countrycode)(.*)$", "\\2")
```

**Alternatively** - Adapting the RegEx by [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62409799/12892553) to Google Data Studio:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page, "^.*/countrycode(/[^/]+\\.\\w+)$", "\\1")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c7f28115-332d-4e5e-bd83-9c9f56f20c53) as well as a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capturing group and replace with group 1. You could match `/countrycode` literally or use the pattern to match 2 times chars a-z with an underscore in between like `/[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}`

In the replacement use **group 1** `\\1`

```
^.*/countrycode(/[^/]+\.\w+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7N1Hv/1)

Or using a country code pattern from the comments:

```
^.*/[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}(/[^/]+\.\w+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9SK3kJ/1)

The second pattern in parts

- `^` Start of string
- `.*/` Match until the last occurrence of a forward slash
- `[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}` Match the country code part, an underscore between 2 times 2 chars a-z
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `/[^/]+` Match a forward slash, then match 1+ occurrences of any char except `/` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
  - `\.\w+` Match a dot and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string